# Discrepancy when reading serial data from POS systems

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I am working on a project to control a couple of motors using transaction data sent from a POS system to a receipt printer. I split the serial communication using a serial cable splitter that goes to a Raspberry Pi and a thermal printer.

To test the system, I created a simple POS system that sends ESC commands to an EPSON TM-T20II printer. The raspberry pi is able to read all the information being sent to the printer with no errors.

However, there is an issue when I install the same setup with a Posiflex POS system that I have in my restaurant. When I try to read the incoming data, I am not able to get anything but a couple of weird commands. I have checked the Posiflex PP8000 printer settings and I was able to confirm (DIP Switches) that the serial settings are 9600 bps, no parity, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit. The reading part of the code is fairly simple:

```html
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600, parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=1)

While True:
    data = ser.read(1)
    bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
    if bytesToRead:
       data = data + ser.read(bytesToRead)
       encodedData = data.encode('hex')
```

What am I missing where the pi is not reading all the data coming from this other POS set up? if the data being sent is using the same RS232 protocol, shouldn't I just be able to read a hex dump regardless of the protocol of the commands (in case is not ESC or Raster)

Comment: Are you sure the data pins are the same?  I don't know much about printers for POS systems, but there are a few different serial standards out there.  While a null-modem setup would be odd in this case, I'm not convinced that it couldn't happen.  Also, are you printing this data somewhere?  In that loop, you'd just be overwriting encodedData over and over again...

Comment: Yes, the manual states that it uses RS-232 standard to send the commands. Also, the code I put there is just a snippet for the reading part. I do break from the loop and use another function to parse the commands.